# Use ThreadPool or Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I had 1 collection which I was saving the content to a persistent storage. Then I ended up having 3 collections which i like to save to a persistent storage.

At first I was using a ThreadPool to save one collection, but now I have 3 collections.Since each collection goes to a different storage, I dont want to combine them or save to same place.

My question is should i use manual Threads and create one thread for each Save() method or should I create 3 thread pool for each method, or should i call all the 3 methods in one ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem call.

1.First Approach

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => 
             { Save<Foo>(ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus1);
               Save<Bar>(ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus2);
               Save<Car>(ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus3);
             });
```

2. Second Approach

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
               { Save<Foo>ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus); });  
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
               { Save<Bar>(ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus2); });  
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
               { Save<Car>(ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus3); });
```

3. Third Approach. Creating Thread Manually and join them.

While doing these operations I dont want my application to hang. I want it to process and save the data, and complete, but not to affect the foreground processes, the whole application.

What s the best way to do this?

Which one should I use? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Threads buy you more cpu cycles, not more disks.  It isn't clear what the critical resource is here, but very likely not cpu cycles.

Comment: To follow on from @Hans Passant, why do you want to use 3 threads?  Can you not just queue all 3 collections to one thread?  You can load the desired target server/folder/whatever into each item so that the thread knows where to put it.

Comment: well yes, this is not very cpu bound but I want them to happen without affecting the application, that s why i would like to run them as a thread pool. anything better u can think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With .NET 4.0 you can use the Task Parallel Library:

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Save<Foo>(ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus1); });
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Save<Bar>(ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus2); });
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Save<Car>(ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus3); });
```

However, it isn't clear from your question what the critical bottleneck is.  The TPL can't help you if you're bottleneck is Disk IO or network latency.

If you want your main thread to wait for them all to complete, you can do this (there are several ways to do it):

```
    Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Save<Foo>(ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus1); });
    Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Save<Bar>(ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus2); });
    Task t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Save<Car>(ConcurrentCollectionStorage.Bus3); });

    Task.WaitAll(t1,t2,t3);
```

This way the thread running the tasks will wait until they finish.  t1,t2, and t3 will be running asynchronously.

Comment: why dont u call 3 methods inside a single Task but u spawn 3 Task?

Comment: @user177883: it depends on what you want to do.  You can call them all inside one task if you want.  Like I said, it depends on your bottleneck.  If the Save<T> action blocks, you might as well just let them run in one task.

Comment: do they run asynchronously? do they wait each other to finish?

Comment: @user177883: They run asynchronously.  If you want them to run synchronously, from one thread, you can use the `ContinueWith` methods.

Comment: if wrap them in a single Task, parent task, do they still run asynch? and if i put parent.wait(); they run to completion?

Comment: @user177883: Updated my answer with another sample.

Answer (score 3):

> Since each collection goes to a different storage, I dont want to combine them or save to same place.
>
> While doing these operations I dont want my application to hang. I want it to process and save the data, and complete, but not to affect the foreground processes, the whole application.

Queue three threads in the thread pool.

Comment: do i need to join 3 threads within threalpool? and why am i creating threads within threadpool?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using .net 4 you should use TASK instead of calling the ThreadPool API.
If your save operation is short use it as is. in case it is long and that is why you are considering manual thread then you should use task but mark it as "long running"

HTH